# How can I modify positions in a two dimensional array?

Tags: ruby

If I do the following:

```
table = Array.new(
  3,
  Array.new(
    3,
    nil
  )
)

# =>
  [
    [nil, nil, nil], 
    [nil, nil, nil], 
    [nil, nil, nil]
  ]
```

Now I would like to modify the value at index 2 in the second array, so I would do:

```
table[1][2] = 2.343
```

I would now expect to see:

```
# =>
  [
    [nil, nil, nil], 
    [nil, nil, 2.343], 
    [nil, nil, nil]
  ]
```

However what I'm getting is this:

```
[
  [nil, nil, 2.343], 
  [nil, nil, 2.343], 
  [nil, nil, 2.343]
]
```

What am I not getting here?

PS: Running ruby 2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fix with behavior, try next:

```
empty_table = Array.new(3) { Array.new(3) }
```

From array manual:

> Note that the second argument populates the array with references to the same object. Therefore, it is only recommended in cases when you need to instantiate arrays with natively immutable objects such as Symbols, numbers, true or false.

Answer (score 0):

you are essentially saying create an array with three elements, and put this element (the new array) in each space. The element you are putting in the first array, is just created once. The only way I know to do what you want is using a for loop to push as many new arrays into the first array as you need. something like this:

```
table = Array.new(1, Array.new(3, 0))
0..1.each do |i| 
  table.push(Array.new(3, 0)) #add two more arrays to the first dimension
end
```